# Why is my Javascript function not being called when I have invoked it in OnClientClick

Tags: javascript

I have just today learned how to call backend functions from Javascript and my first Javascript function worked. However, when I tried the very same function and calls on a different front end webpage of the same project for the same button, which is delete, the Javascript function is no longer being called. This is so weird. Here is the Javascript function:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function watchdelete() {
        if (drpManufacturer.SelectedItem.Text != "")   // If there is a selected Manufacturer
        {
            return confirm("Are you Sure You want to delete this Dimension Detail?");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please select a Manufacturer first before deleting");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scripman1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here is the OnClientClick call for the delete button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDimensionDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick = " return watchdelete();" OnClick="btnDimensionDel_Click" />
```

Am I doing something wrong? All I did was add a few lines to a Javascript function that was previously working on another page. I have a feeling there is some syntax error in this Javascript function but you will have to excuse me as I am new to Javascript. Can one use a boolean type for return values in Javascript? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes I was doing something wrong :(. drpManufacturer.SelectedItem.Text != "" is C# code not javascript code. Thank you Alex. Please see correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function watchdelete() {
        var manufacturer = document.getElementById('<%:drpManufacturer.ClientID%>');
        var strManufacturer = manufacturer.options[manufacturer.selectedIndex].value;
        if (strManufacturer)   // If there is a selected Manufacturer
        {
            return confirm("Are you Sure You want to delete this Dimension Detail?");
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select a Manufacturer first before deleting");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. So how do I reference the dropdown list without having to resort to C# code in the JavaScript function. Is that possible or impossible? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: try this if ($('[id$="drpManufacturer"]').val() != '') {...} if you are using jquery

Comment: I took out the drpManufacturer.SelectedItem.Text which is C# code and it now works. My original intention was to push as much backend code which is only for checking things onto the front end, but I guess I am a newbie, however my intentions have been thwarted and the fix does not fully make me happy.

Comment: If you want to have client side validation, you can not use C# code to check value of some property, you must use this approach. 
But best practice is to have both, frontend and backend validation. So after submit you need to have again validation.

Comment: Im not sure if I am using Jquery. Im using Javascript on Asp.Net with C# backend. I need to replace the drpManufacturer.SelectedItem.Text C# expression with something Javascript can understand for the front end dropdown list, otherwise this is only half a job.

Comment: I've edited original answer with javascript code you should use.

Comment: I would sugeest to use `'<%:drpManufacturer.ClientID%>'` instead of using `'SOMEContent_SOMEControl_drpManufacturer'`

Comment: yes you are right :) that is much better. Ill update answer again :)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Now your answer is fully correct and performs what I want. Thank you very much. I am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

remove `return` statement:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDimensionDel" runat="server" Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick="watchdelete()" OnClick="btnDimensionDel_Click" />
```

Comment: If I do remove the return statement will it still have the same functionality? I mean will it not call btnDimensionDel_Click if the Javascript returns false and call it if it returns true? I thought return was necessary for this.

Comment: If I do take out the return statement will OnClick function still be called if JavaScript returns true?

Comment: Putting return there or taking out does not alter behaviour either way. The line it did not like is the drpManufacturer.SelectedItem != "" which is C# code being put inside a Javascript client side function. My intention is to push validation to the client side.

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman you are really confused about how client/server side code works... it is not easy to explain this there